# Como filtrar datos en tablas distintas en una vista en laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Tengo en una vista una tabla con una serie de campos, y me gustaría filtrar esos campos (dentro de la misma vista) en tablas distintas.

Esta vista trae unos campos desde la base de datos, mediante una consulta SQL con Eloquent de Laravel en el controlador, en una variable denominada **`$horarios`**:

**Este es el controlador que recibe los datos desde una primera vista**

```
public function horarios($id,Request $request){

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('fecha')));

    $horarios = HorariosNew::join('cancha','cancha.id','=','horario.cancha_id')
      ->leftJoin('reserva','reserva.horario_id','=','horario.id')
      ->where('horario.hora_inicio','>',date('Y-m-d H:m:s'))
      ->where('horario.hora_inicio','LIKE',$fecha.'%')
      ->where('cancha.complejo_id',$id)
      ->groupBy('horario.id','horario.hora_inicio','reserva.horario_id','cancha.nombre','cancha.deporte','reserva.estado_reserva_id','reserva.horario_id')
      ->orderBy('cancha.nombre','asc')
      ->orderBy('horario.hora_inicio','asc')
      ->get(['horario.id','horario.hora_inicio','cancha.nombre as cancha','cancha.deporte','reserva.estado_reserva_id','reserva.horario_id']);


    //Y REDIRECCIONA A LA VISTA EN DONDE TENGO LA TABLA
    return view('reservar-cancha-horarios',['complejo'=>$id,'horarios'=> $horarios]);
  }
```

A continuación dejo un ejemplo de como aparecen los datos, los cuales están todos juntos, y es en donde busco que eso mismo me aparezca en tablas distintas.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**El campo a filtrar es el nombre de la cancha.** El cual quiero que se muestre en distintas tablas dentro de la vista junto con sus datos correspondientes.

De momento lo que fui intentando fue lo siguiente:

En las siguientes lineas de mi tabla en la vista:

```
<table>
...
@elseif($horario->cancha = 'Cancha 1')
    <form method="POST"  action="{{route('reservar-confirmar',['complejo'=>$complejo])}}">                                
        <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
        <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
        <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
        <td class="text-primary">Disponible</td>
        {!! Form::token() !!}
        <td>
            <input type="submit" name="guardar" class="btn btn-danger" id="btn-seleccionar" value="Seleccionar">
        </td>
    </form>
@endif  
...
</table>
```

Logre mostrar solo la cancha 1 en la tabla.

Para hacer lo mismo con las demás solo debía repetir la estructura completa de la tabla, modificando lo que fuese necesario.

Aunque se que esto fallará si ese campo que trae desde la base de datos cambia a un valor distinto, siendo ese el caso me mostraría la tabla vacía.

Por lo cual no se muy bien como compararlo consigo mismo, para que siempre sea el mismo valor y en consecuencia muestre las canchas correspondientes en distintas tablas.

Comment: vamos a ver si entendí bien...lo que quieres hacer es agrupar los datos por cancha, y estos grupos mostrarlos en tablas individuales? es decir, una tabla por cada cancha?

Comment: Así es, cada cancha con sus datos correspondientes en tablas distintas, en la misma vista.

Comment: La consulta con eloquent tal y cual la pusiste te funciona? me resulta raro, ya que orderBy no existe en eloquent, es valido para query builder.

Comment: @FranIslas. Si existe respondí a tu pregunta indicando la documentación de Laravel, además porque concretamente si funciona, me agrupa los datos por la canchas y horarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Respondo a mi pregunta logré solucionar el dilema.

Lo que hice fue lo siguiente:

En mi controlador que recibía los datos desde una vista anterior agregue un campo más, en el `group by` y luego lo asigne como si fuese una variable.

```
public function horarios($id,Request $request){

    $fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('fecha')));

    $horarios = HorariosNew::join('cancha','cancha.id','=','horario.cancha_id')
        ->leftJoin('reserva','reserva.horario_id','=','horario.id')
        ->where('horario.hora_inicio','>',date('Y-m-d H:m:s'))
        ->where('horario.hora_inicio','LIKE',$fecha.'%')
        ->where('cancha.complejo_id',$id)
        ->groupBy('horario.id','horario.hora_inicio','reserva.horario_id','cancha.nombre','cancha.deporte','reserva.estado_reserva_id','reserva.horario_id', 'horario.cancha_id')
      ->orderBy('cancha.id','asc')
      ->get(['horario.id','horario.hora_inicio','cancha.nombre as cancha', 'horario.cancha_id as id_cancha','cancha.deporte','reserva.estado_reserva_id','reserva.horario_id']);

  return view('reservar-horarios',['complejo'=>$id,'horarios'=> $horarios]);
}
```

Agregué el id de la cancha de mi tabla horarios, y lo llame **id_cancha.**

```
->groupBy('...','horario.cancha_id')
      ->orderBy('cancha.id','asc')
      ->get(['...','horario.cancha_id as id_cancha']);
```

Luego en la vista solo me quedo validar aquello con una sentencia `IF-ElSE`

```
<table class="table">
    <thead style="color: black;">
        <tr>
            <th>Horarios</th>
            <th>Cancha</th>
            <th>Deporte</th>
            <th>Estado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody style="color: grey;">
        @foreach($horarios as $horario)
            <tr>
                @if($horario->estado == 1)
                    <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                    <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                    <td class="text-danger">Ocupado</td>
                    <td></td>
                @elseif($horario->id_cancha == 1)
                    <form method="POST"  action="{{route('MyRoute')}}"> 
                        <td>{{$horario->hora_inicio}}</td>
                        <td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>
                        <td>{{$horario->deporte}}</td>
                        <td class="text-primary">Disponible</td>
                        {!! Form::token() !!}
                        <td>
                            <input type="submit" value="Seleccionar">
                        </td>
                    </form>
                @endif      
            </tr>
        @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Después solo quedaba repetir la estructura de la tabla completa y mostrar una cancha diferente, modificando la siguiente linea, para la cancha que se quiera mostrar logrando separar los datos, que mostraba, en tablas distintas:

```
...
@elseif($horario->id_cancha == 2)
    <tr><td></td></tr>
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo puedes hacer con [groupBy()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-groupby). Solo debes pasarle el nombre de UNA columna, de este modo te lo va a agrupar correctamente. Tu controlador debería quedar así:

public function horarios($id,Request $request){

```
$fecha = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request->input('fecha')));

$horarios = HorariosNew::join...
     // Resto de la consulta..

      ... 
$horarios = $horarios->groupBy("cancha.nombre");

//Y REDIRECCIONA A LA VISTA EN DONDE TENGO LA TABLA
return view('reservar-cancha-horarios',['complejo'=>$id,'horarios'=> $horarios]);
```

}

**Importante:** Debes sacar el groupBy() de tu consulta y dejar solo el que agregué. También lo puedes hacer en la consulta directamente si deseas, pero creo que de este modo queda mas legible. Por otro lado, revisaría el tema de los orderBy(), me resulta raro ya que según tengo entendido no existe dicho metodo para eloquent. Saludos!

Comment: Eso funciona bien pero **me sigue mostrando todo junto,** en una tabla  y probé en separar pero me mostraba las canchas repetidas, y como expliqué en la pregunta no puedo hacer una comparacion por la cancha porque esta linea `<td>{{$horario->cancha}}</td>` trae el nombre, cuando intento comparar por el `id`, por otro lado el `orderBy()` si existe, revisa estos 2 enlaces en donde se utiliza de distintas formas, [Eloquent Laravel Docs 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent) y [Database Query Builder Laravel 5.6](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries)